# How to programmatically create Pictureboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to receive images from a client.

I'm going to need to create an variable amount of `Pictureboxes` based on how many they send.

Is this possible to do in C#?

When created I'm also going to need to set a tag to them.

The client also has an option to send a stream of images to the server, like a video. However, I need to be able to identify what `Picturebox` their last image went in.

That is where I'm going to be using the `Picturebox.Tag` option. However to do this I need to know the name of the `Picturebox`. Something I'm not sure how I'm going to know if I'm creating them programmatically.

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to create a PictureBox for every single image you receive in a "stream of images, like a video".  One is enough.

Comment: It makes no sense either. "It makes no sense whatsoever to create a PictureBox for every single image you receive in a "stream of images, like a video". One is enough."

Comment: @RandRandom Im creating a windows form, sorry I Should of Specified.

Comment: No @HansPassant you don't understand, If they're only sending images I want an image per box. However if they're sending a stream I want to be able to edit the tag of 1 picturebox so I can refer back to that one picture box for each stream of  bytes that are received. It won't create multiple boxes for a video stream.

Comment: @RandRandom Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of picture boxes:

```
private List<PictureBox> boxes = new List<PictureBox>();
```

Add to it and the controls any new picture boxes:

```
private void AddPictureBox()
{
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox(); 
    // plus other initialisation

    boxes.Add(pb);
    Controls.Add(pb);
}
```

To access the last box added:

```
PictureBox pb = boxes.Last();
```

Comment: Thankyou! This is just what I was looking for.

Comment: I was wondering how I would go about selecting the location of this new picturebox? I have multiple tabs on my application, How do I specify which tab the picturebox enters?

Comment: I believe the tab is a control container so you would add it to tab.Controls